# array values assign inside function but shows empty outside

Tags: php, arrays, magento

I'm working on magento site and  facing strange error when array values assign inside function and retrieve outside of function.

```
//define array
$ctall=array();
//function for array value assign
function printtest($fg){
//global variable
    global $ctall;

    //just assign to array
    $ctall[rand(10000,100000)]=$fg; 

 //this var dump shows array with vaues  when function calling
//  var_dump($ctall);
}
```

**i call the function here inside an another  function**

```
$categoryTree = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/category')->getCategories($categoryId, 0, true);
$printCategories = function($nodes) use (&$printCategories) {

   foreach ($nodes as $_category):
      $ctdf=$_category->getId();
      $categoryn = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($ctdf);
          if($ctdf!='' && $categoryn->getIsActive()):
                //here call to function by passing a value
                printtest($ctdf);   
          $printCategories($_category->getChildren());       
        endif; 
  endforeach; 


};


$printCategories($categoryTree);

//sleep(10);



// i try to get array results here but it shows empty
var_dump($ctall);
```

Anyone know how to fix this, i tried hours without luck. Thank You

Comment: try this example https://3v4l.org/SVfrM

Comment: I don't think all code what you shown are in the same file. because if it was it have to work. (As i can see second-code used amgento syntaxes while first-code is normal php function syntaxes)

Comment: above one also not working, the first function i use for explain simply which also have some magento codes too

Comment: you think its a php setting or something

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove all declaration of $ctall, and try this:

```
//remove define array, don't define it
// $ctall=array();

function printtest($fg){

    if(!isset($GLOBALS['ctall'])){
        $GLOBALS['ctall'] = array();
    }
    //assign to global
    $GLOBALS['ctall'][rand(10000,100000)]=$fg;
}
```

on outside, dump like this:

```
var_dump($GLOBALS['ctall'])
```

Comment: same results mate array(0) { }

Comment: Maybe you call from inside another function or class, try add:
`global $ctall;`
before: `var_dump($ctall);`

Comment: no mate it's outside the functions, i just add that to test after add var_dump print null instead of array(0) { }

Comment: try to declare `static $ctall=array();` on before `$categoryTree = Mage::getResourceModel.....` and delete declaration on before the function, make sure you just declare $ctall once.

Comment: i add that top of the file same get same empty results, i see clearly it saves values when i var_dump inside that function, not sure why outside shows empty

Comment: okay, the last solution, you can use $_GLOBALS variable directly, I will edit my answer

Comment: it seems working fine, Thanks a lot for help, is there have any though about why the global keyword not working, again thanks for the answer

Answer (score 1):

Try to push instead of assigning.Try this:

```
$ctall[][rand(10000,100000)]=$fg; //notice the empty square brackets
```

you can try this   also:

```
function printtest($fg){
  global $ctall;
  $new_array =array();
  $new_array[rand(10000,100000)] = $fg;
  array_merge($ctall, $new_array);
}
```

Comment: Are you serious right now? it will give him another issue also.->`can't use empty index for assignmenrt`

Comment: Now it even worse.You are unnecessarly using extra code.

Comment: @Alive to Die : Can you then tell us how to push element into associative array? I mean push not assign

Comment: In OP's case there is no need of `push`. His question is why global is also not working in his case. Your answer is far away from what he is asking

Comment: but did you realize that I'm trying to push and not make assignment?

Comment: Ok leave it man. Please ask OP to check your code and deside. He will tell you that your code worked or not.Meanwhile you can check other answer to atleast  see where the question is heading right now

Comment: Ok, I hope you understand now.